# Get the whole List as Json from a List in R

Tags: r, list, get, fromjson

Hello So I am using get request to github api:

```
commitsPublic <- GET("https://<host-name>/api/v3/search/commits?
q=is:public+org:<ORG-NAME>",
add_headers(Authorization= "token <your-Token>", Accept= 
'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'))
```

## commitsPublic

And I get:

## 156 Items (Total Count)

```
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 291 kB
{
  "total_count": 156,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
  (I removed the Items Since they are not important)
```

But when I try to convert the Json:

## Shows raw data which is not structured and readable

```
jsonRespText<-content(commitsPublic,as="text") 
jsonRespText
```

## Convert to Json:

```
toJson <- fromJSON(jsonRespText)
toJson
```

## Returns:

```
$items[[30]]$score
[1] 1
```

It returns a List with items up to the number 30 " items[[30]]

## and items[[31]] is NULL

So what I am asking is how can I get the 156 Listed items all of the list from Json text. I have another get request which gives me 10.000 Total Commits. But when I convert from Json the list has 30 still. So any help would be grateful thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Github API paginates to 30 results. Pagination information is in the response Link header.

```r
library(httr)

commitsPublic <- GET("https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=is:public+org:rstudio",
                     add_headers(Accept = 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'))

headers(commitsPublic)$link
#> [1] "<https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=is%3Apublic+org%3Arstudio&page=2>; 
#> rel=\"next\", 
#> <https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=is%3Apublic+org%3Arstudio&page=34>; 
#> rel=\"last\""
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

This tells us where the next page is located, and that there are 34 pages in total in this instance.

*Reference: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/*

Comment: I see. But I have a git request with 100.000 Total count. I have to like do this 300 times?

Comment: Basically, yes. There's also a `per_page=` parameter that can be increased to 100.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`gh` package](https://github.com/r-lib/gh) whose `gh()` function has a `.limit` parameter that can be set to `Inf` and does this for you

Comment: Per page works but for 100k I need to do x1000 :D. Do you know how the gh() function works?

Comment: You can see how it's done at https://github.com/r-lib/gh/blob/master/R/pagination.R . What is the problem with making 1000 calls though? The Search API has a custom rate limit of 30/hour https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/#understanding-your-rate-limit-status (might be different on your instance of GH Enterprise, I'm not familiar with it). That's a 30 minutes job.

Comment: I dont understand how it works.. The limit parameter unfortunately... Well I have much data and I have to work with them so how can I work with them if they are thousands at the same time?

Comment: If you can figure out how the limit parameter works I would really appreciate it!

Comment: There's another problem anyway that I hadn't realised at first, it's the _overall_ limit (including pagination) of 1000 results. Though, again, it seems configurable in GitHub Enterprise (if that's what you're using), you might need to reach out to your administrator about that. (There seems to be a workaround with specifying date ranges to make multiple searches)

Comment: Yeah I am using Github Enterprise. I am an administrator of the Organization. I am doing a project of analysing the commits of students in the University. But the commits are from 330 repositories and from many students and the commits are like 100 Thousands. So is search/org:orgname/commits the right way I am looking for commits? Or is there other way to get all the commits of all the repos within an organization. And ofcourse to get them all as one big list. Which finally I have to convert to data.table  to CSV. To analyse it.

Comment: Thoughts: (1) have a look at https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/migrations/exporting-the-githubcom-organizations-repositories, which might be very big, and mine it directly. Thoughts: (2) have a look at the Github graphql v4 API and write queries that do some of the aggregation directly

Comment: You could avoid the Search API with sth like `set_config(verbose()) ; org <- "rstudio" ;

repos <- gh("https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos", org = org, .limit = Inf) ;

res <- repos %>% 
  map(~ gh("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits", owner = org, 
           repo = .$name, .limit = Inf))`

Comment: Seems doable but where do I pass the authantication token?

Comment: You may add `.send_headers = c(Authorization = "token <your-Token>")` as a `gh()` parameter

Comment: I tried it but for some reason R doesnt respond. It just show the text I try to run and thats it no response.

Comment: when I use the gh() function